Wrapper Auxiliary Method VS Default Arguments for Initialization: Pros/Cons
I have a class in which there are several methods that can act as an "entry point" to its private innards (or the "fruit" thereof).
Said functions might be called multiple times throughout a single "pipeline" as triggered by such an entry point, but only the first call should act as the actual entry point in that it performs a certain initialization action.
Similar use cases show up in situations that aren't necessarily object oriented, of course (off the top of my head: wrappers of recursive functions which initialize something before the recursion itself begins).
Here are examples of two ways by which I'd consider approaching this, illustrated Pythonically:
1. Wrapper Auxiliary Method
...
    def cool_stuff(self):
        self.__init()
        self.__cool_stuff()

    def __cool_stuff(self):
        actual_coolness()  # Might invoke __cool_stuff again.
...

2. Flag Argument With Default Value
...
    def cool_stuff(self, _do_init=True):
        if _do_init:
            self.__init()
        actual_coolness()  # Might invoke cool_stuff again, albeit with init=False.
...

I was wondering if one is considered "preferable" given a language that supports both options, or if it's purely a matter of "taste" (or, in other words: if a convention exists, and if it does, then whether it is mostly-arbitrary or more involved).
An upside I see for #1 is that it leaves implementation-y stuff out of the API (see my admittedly-hesitant use of a leading underscore in #2's _do_init to hint that it is by-design a strange "private argument"), while an upside I see for #2 is that it seems to usually be aesthetically neater, I think.

Consider using decorators.   The original motivation for including decorators in the language is described in PEP-318.
An example below using a decorator to remember whether a method on an instance has been called yet:
from functools import wraps

class MyLittleClass:
    def _do_init(self):
        print("_do_init()")

    def initialising(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def _initialising(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not hasattr(self, 'run_once'):
                self._do_init()
                setattr(self, 'run_once', True)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return _initialising

    @initialising
    def cool_stuff(self):
        print("cool_stuff()")
        
    @initialising
    def more_cool_stuff(self):
        print("more_cool_stuff()")        
        
obj = MyLittleClass()
obj.cool_stuff()
obj.cool_stuff()
obj.more_cool_stuff()

Output:
_do_init()
cool_stuff()
cool_stuff()
more_cool_stuff()

(Note: The attribute is tied to the instance/self rather than the class)

Thanks a lot; a very helpful answer: great to know about functools.wraps! I've been wondering, though, about the two options I'd presented specifically as well (from a point of view that is less Python-bound, though of course not entirely language-agnostic since it's all language feature-dependent), or maybe alternatives that aren't necessarily dependent on the existence of decorators. Would really appreciate it if you have some insight about this as well.

@Shay Even when decorators aren't available as a first-class language feature, most popular languages support metaprogramming, aspect-oriented-programming, higher-order functions, and other features to help decouple 'cross-cutting' concerns from your main codebase (usually meaning there is some library/framework available to help too).    Personally I'm not a fan of either approach, and would prefer to look at something that depends on the language or a library.  However the second approach in particular makes me think of Flag Argument

Thanks a lot for the input :) The points about flag arguments are rather compelling as reasons to avoid my method #2. Also: I just had the chance to take a more careful look at your proposed solution and realized that it doesn't do exactly what I was aiming for, I think (I misguessed the function of functools.wraps); if cool_stuff were to call itself another n times then _do_init() would be invoked a total of n+1 times as well, once for each invocation. What I shoot for is having it run only once every time I (as a user of the class) call cool_stuff. Do I misunderstand your suggestion?

@Shay Ah, sorry about that - I'd assumed the instance already had some way of tracking whether the initialisation had happened so had just focused on the 'wiring'.   For tracking this without adding code into the class or its functions, you could allow the decorator to add an attribute to the instance, but there are other places it could go depending on whether the initialisation is needed per-instance or whether it's static and applies to the lifetime of the program (Updated with a per-instance example).

Thanks a lot, Ben; I really appreciate all your help. I think this method is super neat and I definitely like it, and it sure does drives home your point regarding using a language's strengths rather than avoiding them. :-)
